# Different ASP.NET web site types/icons

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

The following screenshot shows what I believe is an ASP.NET website and a web application. Am I correct and which one is which?

[image]
(Apologies for maybe duplicate, typed in earlier but can't find it now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. This shows difference between Website and Web application difference.

Left on is Web application while right one is your web site.

Here is link which shows difference between Web site and Web application project in asp.net.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590(v=vs.110).aspx

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks yes it does - just double checking my project is using the type I expected